# STEP 3 1989 Q6: Trouble understanding what is meant by focus of two tangents.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

In a STEP past paper I am doing I got to the last part of question 6 but I can't seem to understand what is given to me. Could someone enlighten me what is meant by a focus of two lines or tangents? I have attatched the question bellow
[image]

Comment: They are referring to the focus of the *conic*.

Comment: @Tavish Oh as in the fucci?

Comment: Is that another term for foci?